# git: how to deal with to early branching

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I did something like:

```
          y1-y2-y3-y4-y5
         /          /
x1-x2-x3           /
         \        /
          z1-z2-z3
```

But now I want to have changes from y1 and y2 also in z2 and the the next ones.

z3 was already merged into y5.

What we want to achieve is something like:

```
         y1-y2-y3-y4-...- throw away
         /   \       
x1-x2-x3       \    
         \       \ 
          z1-z2-z3-z4- continue work with changes from y1&y2
```

How to deal with that problem?

1. cherry pick
2. on z3: git merge y2? ( on z3 merge  seems to work. )
3. something else

Some additional info:

The repo exists on 3 servers. ( No permanent network excess possible ) Each clone access all remotes from time to time. In case of using `rebase` I fear of some side effects.

Comment: I'd just `cherry-pick` y1, y2

Comment: If this is a common occurrence, you should probably change your git workflow to use something more suited towards what you actually want to accomplish

Comment: @JoePhillips: No, this is the result of a bugfix branch which can not be used completely. But the first part of work is useful and should be merged now.

Comment: @Klaus Will the rest of the commits ever be used? If not, just do a hard reset locally back to the commits you want and then merge the branch into the other branch. Simple. Or just check out the commit you want and merge that

Comment: @JoePhillips: That is what I have as point 2) on my question. I create a new branch on z3 to keep z3 if something went wrong. On that I simply merges with y2. Seems to work. If everything is checked I simply merge that new branch back to z branch ( will be z4 ) in the given example. But this sounds as the opposite of your proposal?! So it looks that a hard reset on y was not needed and can be kept.

Answer (score 1):

The rebase command was actually base for this.

Currently your branch is based at x3 and you want to move its base to y2 so

```
git checkout z 
git rebase y2
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

For more examples

Comment: Is this safe if multiple checkouts exists already? Something special if repo is cloned to multiple servers. I fear a bit for rebase. Got a lot of work by a "nearly perfect rebase" in the past :-)

Comment: @klaus You haven't provided enough details to really know if this is safe. You don't mention anything about using forks or whether or not you want to merge in an entire branch or just a commit or two here and there

Comment: @JoePhillips: All remotes have the same content and are in sync actually. The branch I want to merge/rebase/... is a linear line of commits, but the concurrent branch was merged some times to the one which now should be mered... ahh yes: I will update my question to get a better picture.